Removing line or row if value is empty or null in Arcade
I am trying to remove lines in a pop-up which have blank values or .
Example below:
var fieldz = { Category: DomainName($feature, "Category"), Project: $feature.ProjectName, Stat: $feature.Status}

// Add a field base on attribute in another field
if($feature.Category == 'Trt' ) // Need to use code from domain 
{
fieldz["LandYN"] =$feature.LandscapeLevel // 
};  

// Add fields if a field is populated
if(!IsEmpty($feature.Comments) )
{
fieldz["Comment"] = $feature.Comments
fieldz["ProjType"] = $feature.ProjectType
}; 


return {      
type: 'fields',    
title: 'Hello World', // Use '' to hide title and description in popup.
description : 'describe???',
fieldInfos:  [
{fieldName: "Project"}, 
{fieldName: "Category"}, 
{fieldName: "LandYN"},  
{fieldName: "Stat"}, 
{fieldName: "Comment"},
{fieldName: "ProjType"},
],
      attributes:  fieldz    }


Are you using Arcade for a pop-up in ArcGIS Pro or ArcGIS Online?

Using Arcade in ArcGIS Pro to publish a new service though if it is easier in AGOL it could be done on the item details > Visualization

Your code actually will give you only the field that have the attributes. Here's a test I ran using a modification of your code
var test = ''
var fieldz = {Category: 'Ongoing', Project: 'Testing', Stat: 45}

if (!IsEmpty(test)) {
  fieldz['LandYN'] = 'Yes';
  fieldz['Comment'] = 'This was tough!'
  fieldz['ProjType'] = 'Basic'
}

return { 
  type : 'fields', 
  title: 'Hello World', // Use '' to hide title and description in popup.
  description : 'describe???',
  fieldInfos:  [
    {fieldName: "Project"}, 
    {fieldName: "Category"}, 
    {fieldName: "LandYN"},  
    {fieldName: "Stat"}, 
    {fieldName: "Comment"},
    {fieldName: "ProjType"},
  ],
  attributes: fieldz
}

This resulted in this popup (in the Visualization tab in the Items detail of a feature service)
If I changed the test variable to contain some text, the extra fields were added.
